Nifi InvokeHTTP processor to get SessionID from Znuny OTRS
I'm trying to get tickets from Znuny OTRS with Apache Nifi. I want to do this, using SessionID, not only username and password.
I don't know how to securely get/create SessionID from OTRS without sending Username en Password plaintext in the url.
I'm using the InvokeHTTP processor.
I tried using parameters, but I can't use sensitive parameters in a non-sensitive field.
Does anyone know how to do this?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

SO is for programming questions

You can change the web service configuration to use POST/PATH as the request method and move the credentials to the body. Or you can add them to the header of the HTTP request (see https://doc.znuny.org/znuny_lts/admin/webservices/provider/index.html#http-header-authentication). Just a hint: no need to use a session, it's optional.
